# Matching Lines in a text file based on values in CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

**Hi Everyone,**

I am having trouble with the below script.  Here is the requirement:

1) Each text file needs to be compared with a single CSV file.  The CSV file contains the data to that if present in the text file should match.

2) If the data in the text file matches, output the matches only and run jobs etc..

3) If the text file has no matches to the CSV file, exit with 0 as no matches are found.

I have tried to do this, but what I end up with is matches, and also non matches.  What I really need is to match the lines, run the jobs,exit, if text file has no matches, then return 0

```
$CSVFIL = Import-Csv -Path $DRIVE\test\csvfile.csv
$TEXTFIL = Get-Content -Path "$TEXTFILFOL\*.txt" |
  Select-String -Pattern 'PAT1' | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'PAT2' | 
      Select-String -Pattern 'TEST'

ForEach ($line in $CSVFIL) {

If ($TEXTFIL -match $line.COL1)  {

Write-Host 'RUNNING:' ($line.JOB01)

} else {

write-host "No Matches Found Exiting"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this a different way. First you need to find matches, if there are matches then process else output 0.

```
$matches = @()

foreach ($line in $CSVFIL)
{
    if ($TEXTFIL -contains $line.COL1)
    { $matches += $line }
}

if ($matches.Count -gt 0)
{
    $matches | Foreach-Object {
        Write-Output "Running: $($_.JOB01)"
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Output "No matches found, exiting"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I would like to add some additional criteria to match to the csv file such as -contains $line.COL1 -and $CD1 -match $line.COL2

Comment: The `-match` comparator is to use Regex, unless COL2 contains a Regex statement you're not going to get what you're expecting. How do you want to compare it? Also would just like to thank you for bumping me over 1,000 rep =D

Comment: Happy to bump you over 1000 :)  I want to compare additional text fields.  -match $env.computername.  That narrows down the list to the machine I am on as we will run this on a few other machines.

Comment: Use `-eq` if you're expecting an exact match, as I said the `-match` comparator is for matching text to Regex logic. For example: `"!£$%^&*()" -match "!£$%^&*()"` returns $false

Answer (score 0):

```
$CSVFIL = Import-Csv -Path "$DRIVE\test\csvfile.csv"
Get-Content -Path "$TEXTFILFOL\*.txt" |
where {$_ -like "*PAT1*" -and $_ -like "*PAT2*" -and $_ -like "*TEST*" } |
  %{
  $TEXTFOUNDED=$_; $CSVFIL | where {$TEXTFOUNDED -match $_.COL1} | 
     %{    [pscustomobject]@{Job=$_.JOB01;TextFounded=$TEXTFOUNDED;Col=$_.COL1 } }        

  }
```