# I want to match a string from text files to CSV file, if match found add from 3rd column in CSV

Tags: powershell

I have 7000+ text files that I need to check for a line / string (NAME=??????) and lookup in a csv file to see if there is a match.  If there is a match in the the csv file then I want to add the content from the third column in the csv to the original matching text file as a new line.

Example of a few lines from the original text file:

```
DATE=23/10/2018 09:10
NAME=CAP9000323  - String / line to find in CSV file
USER=
SERIAL=
BIOS="Mar 20 2009 12:00AM" "LENOVO" "LENOVO - 12e"
HWPLATFORM=LENOVO 6258A92
MANUFACTURER=LENOVO
CPU=CPU0 2200 Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz Model 15, Stepping 13
MEMORY=3652724
NETWORK="7_e1kexpress" "10.248.93.8
```

Example of CSV file:

```
Column1,Column2.4,Location
NAME=0LJA4Y,10.248.68.50,LOCATION=LEVEL 06
NAME=BTCSHFQLA01,10.91.140.10,
NAME=CAO9000961,10.248.146.172,LOCATION=WIRELESS
NAME=CAP6040638,10.68.192.151,LOCATION=GRN HO-
NAME=CAP9000035,10.248.146.171,LOCATION=WIRELESS
NAME=CAP9000066,10.161.240.26,LOCATION=GDNS-
NAME=CAP9000077,,
NAME=CAP9000323,10.248.93.8,LOCATION=FIRST START-  - Match would find this line and copy column 3 content 'LOCATION=FIRST START-' back to original text file that it matched
NAME=CAP9000352,,
NAME=CAP9001820,10.248.147.0,LOCATION=WIRELESS
```

Expected result:

```
DATE=23/10/2018 09:10
NAME=CAP9000323 - String / line to find in CSV file
USER=
SERIAL=
BIOS="Mar 20 2009 12:00AM" "LENOVO" "LENOVO - 12e"
HWPLATFORM=LENOVO 6258A92
MANUFACTURER=LENOVO
CPU=CPU0 2200 Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz Model 15, Stepping 13
MEMORY=3652724
NETWORK="7_e1kexpress" "10.248.93.8
LOCATION=FIRST START-   - The content from the CSV file, column 3 added to the original text file
```

**Addendum:**

Apologies, I have been digging around (for a few days) and tried various attempts at code.

This appeared to be the closest to what I'm after - [Matching Lines in a text file based on values in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118121/matching-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-values-in-csv)

My latest attempt being:

```
$CSVFIL = Import-Csv -Path C:\Collector\MissingLookup.csv
$TEXTFIL = Get-Content -Path "C:\Collector\Jobs\*.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'NAME='

$matches = @()

foreach ($line in $TEXTFIL) {
    if ($CSVFIL -contains $line.COL1) {
        $matches += $line.COL3
    }
}

if ($matches.Count -gt 0)
{
    $matches | Foreach-Object {
        Add-Content $TEXTFIL
    }
}
```

The results I get is it either does nothing or nothing gets written back to the original text file.

Comment: Your code names the 3rd field `COL3` while your csv has the header `Location` and you are iterating the **TXT** file not the **CSV**, the $line from the $TXTFIL has no property `.COL3`

Comment: Thank you, your advice was useful and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
$CSVFIL  = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Collector\MissingLookup.csv'

# get a list of FileInfo objects for all .txt files in the directory and test each of them for the pattern
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Collector\Jobs\*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $textMatch = $_ | Select-String -Pattern '(NAME=.*)'

    # if we have found a file containing the pattern.
    if ($textMatch) {
        # iterate over the items in the CSV file to see if we can match it with the found string
        foreach ($item in $CSVFIL) {
            if ($item.Column1 -eq $textMatch.Matches[0].Value) {
                # append the value from the 3rd column in the CSV called 'Location'
                Add-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $item.Location
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and has helped me understand a little more about PowerShell